# Need performance help in jQuery animation

Tags: jquery, performance

Trying to do this:
function getRec receives a string say (1,3,4). It then splits it into an array. It then calls addRecBox for each element of the array. 
addRecBox appends some specs to each box. Each one should be fading in. And appear on after the other. 'Add' box is appended after that.
Problem 1: Animation is not smooth.
Problem 2: the output seems to be jumbled up.
Here is my code.

```
function getRec(arrayS)
{  
recArray = arrayS.split(',');
addRecoBox(0,recArray.length);
}

function addRecoBox(i,x){
var $div = $("<div>", {id: recArray[i], class: "recH"});
$("#recHolder").append($div);
addSpecs(recArray[i],0,data[recArray[i]].specfication.length);
$('#'+recArray[i]).append('<div>Add</div>');
    if(i<x){
        i++;
        addRecoBox(i,x);
    }
}

function addSpecs(i,j,x){ 
var $specDiv = $("<div>", {id: "spec"+i+"_"+j, class: "specHolder"});
$specDiv.html(data[i].specfication[j]);
$('#'+recArray[i]).append($specDiv); 
$specDiv.fadeIn( 800, function() {
if (j<x){
    j++;
    addSpecs(i,j,x);    
    }
});
```

}

Any help is most appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/dv2utex6/6/

Comment: create a demo if possible in jsfiddle.net

Comment: Solely concerning the `fadeIn` animation not working: the element is added fully visible, if it's hidden (preferably before adding), the fadeIn should work. For example `$('#'+recArray[i]).append($specDiv.hide()); `  (http://jsfiddle.net/dv2utex6/8/)

Comment: I tried different things and reached here... http://jsfiddle.net/dv2utex6/11/
But the thing is, the output should have been<br />p<br />q<br />r<br />s<br />Add<br />1<br />2<br />Add<br />fu<br />ba<br />r<br />Add

Somehow the first for loop isnt happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/dv2utex6/13/)**

Ok finally, after so much experiments, I found so many issues in your code and I've listed some of them below:

> - `specification` spelling was incorrect in data[0] and data[1] and data[2] and in `addSpecs` calling area and inside function too. Check that in your
>     fiddle. So it was giving `error` when it reached `.specification` for
>     1st `data`
> - You were calling `addspecs` in `addRecoBox` before checking for `i` value less than `x` and that was causing issue while appending last
>     `data`
> - In `addSpecs` you were appending to mismatched element i.e. `$('#'+recArray[i]).append($specDiv);` whereas you used to pass the
>     value of Array and not `index` in `addSpecs` which is being called
>     from `addRecoBox and that made your whole`data` to append
>     incorrectly:

Check your **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dv2utex6/6/)** on the above things and you will find the mistakes mentioned and below is the fix for your issues:

```
var data=[];
data[0]={};
data[0].specification = ['a','b','c']; //spelling mistake here
data[1]={};
data[1].specification = ['p','q','r','s']; //spelling mistake here
data[2]={};
data[2].specification = ['x','y','z']; //spelling mistake here
data[3]={};
data[3].specification = ['1','2'];
data[4]={};
data[4].specification = ['fu','ba','r'];

var arrayS = '1,3,4';
var recArray = [];
getRec(arrayS);

function getRec(arrayS)
{  
    recArray = arrayS.split(',');
    addRecoBox(0,recArray.length);
}

function addRecoBox(i,x){
    var $div = $("<div>", {id: recArray[i], class: "recH"});
    $("#recHolder").append($div);
    $('#'+recArray[i]).append('<div>Add</div>');
        if(i<x){
            addSpecs(recArray[i],0,data[recArray[i]].specification.length);
            //spelling mistake in the above 'specification' and moved it inside if statement 
            i++;
            addRecoBox(i,x);
        }
}

function addSpecs(i,j,x){ 
    var $specDiv = $("<div>", {id: "spec"+i+"_"+j, class: "specHolder"});
    $specDiv.html(data[i].specification[j]).hide();
    $('#'+i).append($specDiv);  //You used to assign as recArray[i] here
    console.log($('#'+recArray[i]))
    $specDiv.fadeIn( 800, function() {
    if (j<x){
        j++;
        addSpecs(i,j,x);    
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Guru!!!
Now, I think, it is because of the fadeIn time issue, but I want it to be coming like first p, then q, then r, s, Add, 1, 2, Add, fu, ba, r, Add in that order...
It 'appears' to be appearing like Add, Add, Add, p, 1, fu etc etc
I had got this http://jsfiddle.net/dv2utex6/14/ but I dont know why others are not turning up.

Comment: @Piyush.. I think you haven't read my points properly!! I've mentioned that you have some spelling mistakes in mentioning **specification** for `data`. First please correct that and keep a common word everywhere. See this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/dv2utex6/15/)**. But again its `fadeIn` which is troubling here!!

Comment: Sorry to say but it takes much more time to solve it buddy.. might need to re-write of whole stuff.. better post it as separate problem with fiddle so that people might help you on..

Comment: You too @Piyush.. Happy coding,,

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is how I manage to do it. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dv2utex6/17/).

```
var recArray = arrayS.split(',');

addRecoBox(0);

function addRecoBox(i){
var $div = $("<div>", {id: recArray[i], class: "recH"});
$("#recHolder").append($div);
addSpecs(i,recArray[i],0,data[recArray[i]].specification.length);
}

function addSpecs(index,i,j,x){
var $specDiv = $("<div>", {id: "spec"+i+"_"+j, class: "specHolder"});
$specDiv.html(data[i].specification[j]);
$specDiv.css('display','none');
$('#'+i).append($specDiv); 
$specDiv.fadeIn( 800, function() {
j++;
    if (j<x){
    addSpecs(index,i,j,x);    
    } else {
        $('#'+i).append('<div id="add'+i+'">Add</div>');
        $('#add'+i).css('display','none');
        $('#add'+i).fadeIn(800, function(){
            index++;
            if (index<recArray.length){
            addRecoBox(index);
            }
        });
    }
}); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified

```
$specDiv.html(data[i].specfication[j]);
```

to this:

```
$specDiv.html(data[i].specfication[j]).hide();
```

does that look better?

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ahvonenj/dv2utex6/9/